# Adding existing Web Site in IIS to Git in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, vs-web-site-project

I am trying to add a repository containing the html pages, javascript scripts, images, and c# code files for my website hosted on IIS. I have a solution in visual studio 2017 that has the website added as a project, but as Web Site's go, the actual files for the website are in a different folder than the project (inetpub vs the defualt project file location). When I tried to add the project to git from visual studio it says the portions of the website outside of the project folder will not be added or maintained by git. Is there any way to get my code onto git?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first time using git, I recommend checking out a few of the courses available online, such as [Github's Hello world](https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/) or [their Try It tool](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1), or a tutorial offered by someone else, like [this one](http://kbroman.org/github_tutorial/pages/init.html).

There is also an official book on how to use git and how it works, available online for free, [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

Keep in mind that while these links are mostly around github, you can use the tools here with any git host, like GitLab, BitBucket, or even your own self hosted solution